# How to use differential equations to write $x(t)$ in terms of $y$ and $y_0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The equations are:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
x' & = & \mbox{}-a\,x & + & b\,xy
\\
y' & = &  c\,y & - & d\,xy
\end{array}\right.
$$
They want me to write an equation for $x(t)$ in terms of $y$ and $y_0$ only.

How would I do this?

Comment: What is $y_0$ ?

Comment: a constant, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=x'=x(t)(-a+ y(t) b)\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=y'=y(t)(c- x(t) d)\tag{2}$$

(1)/(2) leads to:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x}{y}\frac{-a+ y b}{c- x d}\tag{3}$$

or

$$\frac{c- x d}{x}dx=\frac{-a+ y b}{y}dy\tag{4}$$

Integration of (4) leads to

$$ c\log x- x d=-a\log y+b y+y_0 :=A(y,y_0)\tag{5}$$

The solution to (5) can be expressed in terms of [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

$$x= -(c/d)W(-B(y,y_0)) \tag{6}$$

where

$$B(y,y_0)=(d/c) \exp((1/c)A(y,y_0))$$

Comment: You are welcome. If you like the solution, you may accept it. Thanks

Comment: Once I've integrated it, however, I can't get an expression for x(t) in terms of y and y0, can I? This just gives me an equality like: clnx - dx = -alny + by + y0

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{x'}{y'}$.

Comment: I am wondering why this hint got a down vote. Maybe not hinting enough? +1 from me.